# Real time scale bitmap with ScaleGestureDetector

Tags: android

How can I implement a realtime scale bitmap with ScaleGestureDetector without getting any memory warning ? Short question for probably a longer response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following library does a nice job of this.

Subsampling Scale Image View
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Txs for the response. How can I react to resize events in this lib ?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by resize events in this context? This lib is primarily intended to support pinch to zoom/panning etc for large images (I may have misunderstood your original question...was it something else you were looking to support?)

Comment: I choose your option, and txs again... It works well but how can I increase the level of scale, why I cannot scale a bitmap smaller than my layout and last question why it says

Comment: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5100x3300, max=4096x4096)

for  big bitmaps and the lib says it works with 20 000x20 0000 px bitmaps ?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/07.-Configuration  (e.g. `setMinimumDpi()`)